# custom onEdit function that updates external sheet fails for other user, but only when using inputBox

Tags: google-apps-script, inputbox

I'm at a loss to explain the cause. I have a small Google sheet which I copied to my wife to allow her to use. Her version has scripting to update my sheet (if it detects a missing value).

I wrote a custom onEdit() function which is called via [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).  I have confirmed she can edit my sheet: by opening it and hand editing, manually running the script, or by commenting out the inputBox and replacing it with a static value.

The update does occur if:
* She manually triggers the custom_onEdit function from the code -> run menu
* I modify the code to comment out the inputBox and use a static value

Simplified code:

```
function custom_onEdit(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
      col = range.getColumn(), 
      row = range.getRow(), 
      value = range.getValue();

  if (value != "" && sheet.getRange(row,col+1).getValue() === ""){
    Dialog(value);
  }
}

function Dialog(v){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      result;

  result = Browser.inputBox('Populate the value required',Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  if (result != 'cancel'){
    UpdateExternalSS(result,sheet.getName());
  }
}

function UpdateExternalSS(value, name){
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abcd1234').getSheetByName(name);
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(value);
}
```

If I comment out the call to Browser.inputBox and add:

```
//var result = Browser.inputBox('Populate the value required',Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
var result = '9999';
```

It works fine.

(edit) - More reading - is seems the Installable Trigger I setup actually runs as my account, so there should be zero reason why it's not running (I am the owner of both spreadsheets)...

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger, it will run when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has edit access), but it will run as your account.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an update to the above answers. I created and onEdit script for my spreadsheet using Browser.msgBox calls before I knew that it shouldn't work. They work correctly for both simple comments and for seeking answers to yes-no questions. It fails when using Browser.inputBox calls. That is when I found the above answers. In that case, the script simply quits when it encounters the inputBox call.  I tested the script sharing the spreadsheet with another user and found that the msgBox calls still work fine unlike the reports in previous answers.  It is just the inputBox calls that do not.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old bug in Google Apps Script.

1. First reported in 2012: [Installable on edit triggered function fails to continue after msgbox for other users](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1728).
2. Then reported here on Stack Overflow: [Shared spreadsheet, trigger set by one user, msgBox causes script to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14860176)
3. Reported to Google in 2013 [again](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2462), and closed as a duplicate.

#### Workaround

Since we can't use Browser methods in triggered scripts intended for other users, an alternative is to indicate that they should enter certain values in certain cells of a spreadsheet, and get those with an on-edit trigger.

As an aside, I suggest using [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) in scripts run by a trigger, which provide the active range and entered value directly to the script.